# Built-in GLUT with VS 2012 - doesnt work

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012

The only thing I did to use openGL is including `<GL/gl.h>` header file.

In all opengl examples I've seen that was the only declaration used for enabling openGL.

However, it doesn't work. When I create Win32 console application, and write include directive, I suddenly get the whole bunch of different errors. Let me write all of them them:

1) This declaration has no storage class or type specifier
2) Expected a ';'
3) variable WINGDIAPI is not a type name

The first two errors are repeated a lot of times, each one in different line.

These errors appear inside the GL.h file, from 1157th line to 1206th line.

What is wrong?

BTW. I just posted quite similar question here, but it was mostly about a good book on the topic, the title also wasn't suggesting this case, and I didn't get the answer, so I hope it's not a duplicate.

Comment: "*In all opengl examples I've seen that was the only declaration used for enabling openGL.*" I *defy* you to show me a working .cpp file that uses OpenGL that *only* includes `<GL/gl.h>`. There is no such example code that you've seen. No, you only looked for headers that said "gl", and assumed the others weren't important.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `#include <windows.h>` before you `#include <GL/gl.h>`.

That only gets you OpenGL. If you want to use GLUT, you need to download, build, and link to that separately (but you really don't want to -- it's quite old, buggy, and its shortcomings aren't apparently ever going to be fixed). There are various alternative implementations of GLUT, but they follow the same API, so they can only fix a few of the most minor of its shortcomings.